# What makes these questions so different that one of them is bad and the second one is good?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, moderation

Here are two different questions:

1. [What is the best and fastest way to generate data way with std and ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011820/what-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-generate-data-way-with-std-and-ranges)
2. [C++: compile-time "dominoe update" using fold expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78017740/c-compile-time-dominoe-update-using-fold-expressions)

Both have a lot in common in terms of the reason the first question was closed: "*Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.*":

1. Both questions have only one question which splits into three sub-questions; I would even say that in the second case these sub-questions are more standalone and self-sufficient than in the first question.
2. Both questions started with the code which somehow disappointed the user JaMiT for the first question.

Not considering the specific content of the questions (it is quite subjective), I have a question, based on the close reasoning for the first question: what makes these questions so different in these terms(!) that the first one got a downvote and three votes to close, while the second one got an upvote and was answered?

Just curious what lessons could be learn here?

Again, please, don't focus on technical specifics of the first question, it wasn't the official reason to close it and I am quite sure that the person, qualified with `std` and `ranges` can answer this question at a glance. And, really, I don't think it is a good idea to create 3 questions instead of this one.

Comment: I mean, both are less than a week old. Voting in the the short-term is more about hitting the question list with a topic at a time when people interested in that topic are active.

Comment: *"What is the best and fastest"* is also a huge red flag. I'd not be surprised if someone clicked in and downvoted for that specifically.

Comment: @KevinB, I would understand if I named it "Best and fastest" like for advert, but what is wrong with "What is the best and fastest"?

Comment: Because "what is best and fastest" is often shorthand for "I don't know how to determine what is best and fastest for my scenario." If you can't determine what solution is the best for your scenario, why would you expect people who don't have access to your environment to be able to accurately determine that? Most of the time which one is fastest is irrelevant anyway, and which one is "best" is just personal opinion.

Comment: @KevinB, this really sounds strange for me. When I ask such a specific question on the library functions I assume there are lots of people who uses it daily basis and can just answer "it should be used this way - short text and best generated code, so best and fastest". Every library has its basic default approach to handle such things. It was just developed for this. That's why I asked, because I know for sure that any library expert could answer this at a glance.

Comment: Right, but that can be implied. You don't need  "What is the best", you simply need to ask "How do i do X" and people will provide the "best" answer. Don't add useless qualifications to your questions that can't be directly objectively measured. "Best", "most straightforward", "fastest", etc

Comment: @KevinB, thank you, let's give a try and see if it would work. But my question above is different, the closure reason is "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only". Why the second question wasn't closed the same way if this is the reason?

Comment: Because close voters hadn't found it yet.

Comment: @KevinB, not sure. Anyway, do you really think that if I just rename the question if would succeed?

Comment: No, that's not the only problem the question has, it's just one that will quickly attract people ready to close it for that reason. Titles, and the first paragraph of your question, are just very important to whether or not someone clicks on your post.

Comment: @KevinB, or, combining your two answer the idea is to create 3 new duplicating questions instead of one? I have only one question, namely, how to implement this code and shown my effort to solve the problem in three different ways, as it is asked on SO. My question is one and straightforward: how this code should be implemented. What is the reason to split this into 3 questions?

Comment: the rule of thumb is multiple questions are ok, if they're actually just expansions of the same question. In the question you linked that was well received, that's the case for 2 of the questions, but not all three; both answerers ignored the question that was not like the others.

Comment: I've edited the second question you linked since the extra questions asked in it seemed entirely different from their "primary" one and OP had accepted an answer that addressed only the first. If the OP rolls this edit back the question will likely get closed.

Comment: @KevinB, can you suggest a way to rework first question to make it useful and well-received? I can't see a way to split alive creature in a parts without killing it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, that is the part of my question, why for the first question people chose closing and for the second one, editing? I wouldn't mind editing if it helps to get answers, but I was just hit from the dark while another question got a real help.

Comment: In case of your question I'd say your best course would be to change it into a "how to" question where you describe what you want to do and forego adding those attempts and asking people to suggest the best option etc.

Comment: In the case of the second question it was a pretty simple edit from my part where I simply removed stuff, your question would require more effort than that which I don't feel comfortable doing as a non-SME. Note if that question had no answer I'd have simply cast a close vote.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, so the only difference between these two questions is that the first one is understandable by non-SME and second one is hard? (Which one do you mean with "Note if that question had no answer"?)

Comment: @DamirTenishev not really I had difficulty understanding the other question as well but after a bit of research I was able to figure out what it was asking. The difference is that it was quite simple to remove those extra questions due to the way they were stated. In the case of your question I don't feel the focus is really the problem rather it's the fact that you ask for "best way" which is often opinion based. Fixing that would require subject matter expertise which I don't feel equipped with. Also given it would be changing your question quite a bit it is best done by you.

Comment: In general, Meta questions that ask "why is poorly-received question X different from well-received question Y?" - with the implication that one suspects an uneven application of policy, and with the undisclosed information that the meta OP is also the author of question X - are a big red flag for me.

Comment: @il_raffa if I could downvote comments, I'd downvote that one. Although there might be people out there that vote by the users reputation that is generally discouraged and frowned upon by the community. Voting should be on the merits of the post itself and not based on the authors reputation.

Comment: Truth be told I am not overly fond of the second question either, it is not going to be very useful to other people the way it is asked. It is more like a code review rather than stating a good understandable and repeatable problem definition. But the author is very clever posing it as a challenge. As one of the answers states... challenge accepted. Pretty effective tactic, really.

Comment: @Gimby, just to be on the same page, I have nothing against the second question. I took is just as an example from tons of such questions which are not moderated for the reason my one was moderated. On the "challenge" approach, it would be "licit" in case we don't have [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) exactly for this purpose; otherwise like code review (as you mentioned) it should go another place.

Comment: A good [blog post on why "which is faster?"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) questions are problematic. There aren't many things in programming that are "best and fastest" across the broad in every category. Programming is about choosing tradeoffs to suit a particular use case, not silver bullet, one-size-fits-all solutions. But since we don't know your use case, there's no way to say which is "best" for you, which is why "best" questions are generally off-topic.

Comment: @ggorlen, I see where you coming from and I understand the points in this article, but my question was very specific about usage of the library in the way is assumes when was developed. This library has lots of algorithms and approaches to combine them together and with data structures and expect in the area can at a glance answer how to use it. It is not about general topics or distinct cases, it is very specific question.

Comment: Terms that are vague: "correct", "effective", "more straightforward", "best", "better", "fastest". Please define how you measure these goals. Most SO questions are "how can I make the code work/fix specific bug X?" which is pretty easy to measure.

Comment: @ggorlen, well, this is a good point. So, if I have a long implementation which I feel could be replaced with one standard library algorithm and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, how should I ask for the replacement for this code?

Comment: @DamirTenishev as we've mentioned to you before ask a "How to" question (Don't give any attempts, just explain what you want, don't ask for the "best", "fastest", etc.), let the answers give whatever they consider is the "best".

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, after that my question will be closed as "Not showed enough effort to solve the problem". Let's try?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Unfortunately, you were unable to downvote my comment, but someone simply removed it, so the problem is solved. I am pleased to note this. Question for SO: Does the new policy require the removal of all criticism or anything that is not aligned with the mainstream? However, for me, the question ends here.

Answer (score 11):

The first question you link to asks for unspecified things, solicits opinions, and asks for multiple separate things. Each of these reasons is individually cause to close the question.

The second question you link to (at the time of me reading it) asks a very specific, objectively-answerable question: "can I do X, shown below, except without using/relying on Y or Z implementation details". Before the edit a couple of hours ago by Abdul, the question asked multiple separate things, at least one of which was opinion-based. If the question were still in that state when I saw it, it would be worthy of a downvote and a close vote, just like the first question.

---

Questions on Stack Overflow need to:

- be about programming or tools used primarily by/for programmers
- ask one question, not multiple
- clearly specify the criterion that qualifies as a solution to the problem/question
- be objectively answerable

Running afoul of any of these is cause for closure. A question that runs afoul of any of these things and is *not* closed is almost certainly open only because 3 users with the ability to cast close votes and enough knowledge to weigh in have not yet come across said question.

Comment: Well, let me ask from another side, then. In comments to my question @JaMiT says: *Please consider How to Ask ("Introduce the problem before you post any code") and try relying less on your code to communicate what you are trying to do.*. In case this is a violation, why the second question (still have the same formatting after many reviews from moderators after discussion here) is not down voted or closed? Why I am the target for moderation and that question is not? Why so different attitude that one question is edited and another one shot from the dark without any help to improve?

Comment: @DamirTenishev It's generally the author's responsibility to edit their posts to comply with the site rules. In this case, the second question had an objective, on-topic question included in the original revision, so it is easy for another user to edit out extraneous/off-topic questions. The first question you linked, however, did not; it requires an edit by the author to salvage.

Comment: Sorry, you missed my point, that question still violates the aforementioned rule ("Introduce the problem before you post any code") and yet it still open and upvoted. I am not interested in any harm to this specific question, I took it just for a sake of example from tons of similar open and answered questions on SO. My question is, why when tons of questions violate rules here and there, this is missed by moderators and mine was taken as a victim? I have no issues to create new ones, I am just interested how this works.

Comment: You can't just take two samples and compare them 1:1, Clearly two different set of users with different sets of opinions visited one vs the other.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I'm not sure what rule you're talking about. There's no site rule which states that you have to post text before code in a question; many questions do the opposite. You may be conflating _a random user's advice_ with _site rules_ here. The "How to ask" page suggests _advice_ on making a good question, not on making a question on-topic. The two are related, but separate, matters; there are _good off-topic_ and _poor on-topic_ questions (generally, you indicate a question is good/bad by up/down voting. You indicate it's off-topic by close-voting.)

Comment: Please see the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), section "Introduce the problem before you post any code" with **Don't just skip straight to the code!** in bold.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Like my comment above said, that's advice for asking a good, well-received question. Not an on-topic one. Ideally questions are _both_ "good" _and_ "on-topic", but only "on-topic" is a requirement. The order of code vs prose is largely a matter of taste; it would be impractical to create a rule dictating the exact order of contents in posts here.

Comment: I got the point, thank you. Can you please share a link to the rules which states that I mustn't ask more than one question in the question? Not a recommendation, but a rule?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Well, the 'needs focus' closure banner on questions already explains that rule, but sure: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @DamirTenishev If you're asking why two questions were treated differently, the most likely answer is that the questions were seen by different people. Not everyone has the same moderation opinions. Don't take it personally, you're not being singled out for different treatment.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Here is the key: "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.". It seems people who wrote this doesn't feel the difference between "problem" and "question"; or they do, but those who applied this rule, don't. My question has exactly one problem to solve supported by research and many questions which wouldn't lead to many answers. They are just constraints to show that I already considered this, they are not separate questions, they pave the way to the answer to the problem how to write this.

Comment: @DamirTenishev If all three of the interrogative statements ask the same thing, why bother writing it three times and create such confusion? Sounds like it would be simple for you to delete the other interrogative statements from the question, and make sure the one that remains does not run afoul of the other bullet points in my answer (currently all interrogative statements in your question run afoul of the objectivity requirement). At least, a lot simpler than coming to Meta and asking for a whole discussion on the merits of one question vs another.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, thank you, this help, but this doesn't help. :) When moderation done randomly by "opinions", not by logic and rules, this becomes "witch-hunt" even if they say "you are not singled". I would be fine if this "opinion-based" (isn't this what SO asking not to do from users? - I, mean, start opinion-based talks?) moderation process would be supported with explanations which could help improve questions, but when this comes out of darkness like a shot in a back, this is counter-productive.

Comment: One can't image how many times I did this and only to get the same result, people start saying me that I am newbie who even not considered these simple options. Like, why don't you do this way and why don't you ask this question. When I ask, I am moderated. This "give us details" and "be concise" from both sides drive me crazy here.

Comment: "This "give us details" and "be concise" from both sides drive me crazy here." - What you seem to miss is that asking a question on Stack Overflow is **not primarily about** getting a problem solved that motivated the question. (You can ask even if you don't need an answer.) It is about **contributing to the library** that we are building here, as described in the [tour]. So we are looking for enough details to clearly describe a problem that others may need to solve, and no more - a clear specification for how-to problems, and a MRE for understanding errors.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, having different goals we move in the same direction, this is community is what about. SO has its own goals, users have their own. It is nice that it works "synergetically". BTW, what is "MRE"?